# Checking for selected dropdowns on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have lots of content that reveals onchange events, such as:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="ThisBox"]').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'block');     
    } else if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'none');      
    }
});
```

Is there a way of performing these checks when the page loads as well as when an option is changed?

Comment: Put the handler to its own named function, and attach `onchange` and `onload` events to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). You'll just need to fire it *after* all the handlers are bound (i.e. right at the end of your script)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('change');
});
```

This would trigger all `change` handlers to fire on all `checkbox` elements.

The alternative is to refactor:

```
var checkboxHandler = function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'block');     
    } else if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'none');      
    }
};

$('input[type="checkbox"][name="ThisBox"]').change(checkboxHandler).each(checkboxHandler);
```

[Here's a fiddle of the second.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/js7j1tj7/)

Comment: I went with the alternative... I've changed if($(this).is to a specific ID as there are multiple checkboxes etc, so using this was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the code in a separate function and call it on document ready event and onchange events;

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="ThisBox"]').change(function() {
    checker($(this));
});

function checker(data){
if(data.is(':checked')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'block');     
    } else if (data.is(':not(:checked)')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'none');      
    }
};
```

Comment: So would I have lots of different triggers for the function to fire, but they'd all be held under the one "checker" function? So even under dropdowns etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` instead on `change`, like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="ThisBox"]').on("load change", function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'block');     
    } else if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')){
        $('.ThisDiv').css('display', 'none');      
    }
});
```

Comment: This is having no effect, is that because it's asking when the checkbox is loaded rather than when the page is loaded?